# Show that the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

I'm completely lost with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, we have $\mathbb{Z}_4^+=\{0,1,2,3\}$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}^\times = \{1,3,7,9\}$.

Now, I'm going to tell you that $f:\mathbb{Z}_4^+ \to \mathbb{Z}_{10}^\times$ is a homomorphism for which $f(1) = 3$. What you have to figure out is: what are the values of $f(2),f(3),$ and $f(4)$, and why is this an isomorphism?

---

At this point, you should have the following:
$$
\begin{align}
f(1) &= 3\\
f(2) &= f(1+1) = f(1)f(1) = f(1)^2 = 9\\
f(3) &= \cdots = f(1)^3=7\\
f(4) &= \cdots = f(1)^4 = 1
\end{align}
$$
In other words, we've defined $f$ by $f(n) = 3^n \pmod{10}$ for $n = 0,1,2,3$. Now, to prove $f$ is a homomorphism, it suffices to state that
$$
f(n+m) = 3^{n+m}=3^n\cdot3^m \pmod{10} = f(n)f(m)
$$

Comment: So $f(2)=7$, $f(3)=9$, & $f(4)=1$. Why can you say $f$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Not quite.  $$f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1)f(1) = 3\times3 = 9$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: I think so. Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

write down all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{10}$ explicitly. any find a generator by its Cayley Table or by explicit calculation. Now map this generator to $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: Its Cayley Table?

Comment: ya. I mean you can use it to find the power an element.